# select few rows/all rows in pagination table and change value of a column in selected row

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript-controller

I have a pagination html table with checkboxes. I want to be able to select few rows or all rows in the 1st page and change the value of a column in that particular row/or all rows.

**js:**

```
  myFunction:function () {
        
            var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
            for (var i = 1, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
                table.rows[i].cells[6].innerHTML = 'Yes';
              
                }
            
        

I tried this,it worked and I am trying to do this with multiple/all rows but not working when I select few rows.  Please help me with both - few/all rows.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing your list variable three times:

```
for (var i = 0; i < allRecords.length; i++) { // Increment once
    if(allRecords[i].isChecked ){
        selectedRecords.push(allRecords[i++].objAccount.id); // Increment again
        myTable.rows[i++].cells[6].innerHTML = 'yes'; // Increment again
    }
}
```

This will result in a variety of surprising behaviors, including skipped records and incorrect data in `myTable`. You should simply be referencing `i`.

Comment: Hey David, yes you are right so i edited my code its working fine when i select all rows in the 1st page.What can i do to achieve both , i want to select few rows and change the value too .can you help with that. Thank you.

Comment: You've changed your question in a way that makes my answer no longer make sense - please don't do that; it destroys the value for any other reader. To change your data, you would have to write to whatever the underlying data store is, probably `allRecords`.